# DriveApp not being recognised

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I am trying to save some sheets on a spreadsheet as a pdf and from what I've seen online people use DriveApp.

It is not being highlighted as a function on my script which is as follows.

```
function exportToPDF (fileId, folderId){
  var source = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId)
  var blob = source.getAs('application/pdf');
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
  file.setName(source.getName() + '.pdf');
  if(folderId) {
    try{
      var d = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
      moveToFolder_(file, d);
    }
    catch(e){
    }
  }
  return file;
}
```

can someone also explain the Catch line and what it does

Thanks

Comment: Which line is causing error ?

Answer (score 1):

The catch statement lets you handle the error.

```
try{
  var d = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  moveToFolder_(file, d);
}
catch(e){
  console.log("Error: " + e.message);
}
```

[Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)